# Corel uninstall: "The path to the language folder could not be resolved..."

Tags: uninstall

I bought a Windows 7 notebook which had Corel Home Office preinstalled. When I try to uninstall it, I get this error message:

> The path to the language folder could not be resolved, setup cannot
>   continue.

After browsing the web, I found that this error is displayed while installing the program, but I get it whenever I try to uninstall it.

How I can uninstall this software?